# can't delete a row from DataGridView

Tags: datagridview

I'm simply trying to remove a row of DataGridView by taking the first cell's value on each row,

- I have a list, called "bags";
- I have a delete method for the list
- I have the string barcode;

### [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0PEy.png)

the Error I get is:
**'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index'**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4D89.png)

Comment: Are you sure the grids `SelectedRows` collection actually has any rows? It will NOT be used/filled if the grids `SelectionMode` is not set to `FullRowSelect`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f)